# Pointwise convergence from $\liminf$ inequality and convergence of sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm reading the proof of Proposition 3 in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1177005936) (p. 234) in which it seems like the author is saying, **paraphrasing heavily**, that for non-negative functions $f$ and $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ from $T \to \mathbb{R}$ where $T$ is a countable set, also satisfying
$$ \liminf_n f_n(x) \geq f(x), \quad \textrm{for all } x \in T $$
then if we can show
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x \in T} f_n(x) = \sum_{x \in T} f(x) $$
then this implies that in fact $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$.

I can believe this intuitively and it seems like it should be a one-liner *at most*, but I've been staring at this for too long. Can anyone point out the key assumption or observation which makes this work?

Comment: This is not true. Say $g_n(x)\to g(x)$ for every $x$. Now put $f(x) := g(x)$ for every $x$ and $f_n(x) := g_n(x)$, except in one point $x_0$, where we put $f_n(x_0) := f(x_0)+1$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: OK. Thanks, my bad. The example in the paper is not really integration with respect to Lebesgue measure. Sorry to lead you astray there. I've edited.